# c++ handling function pointer across super/base class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a template defined class that handles processing of all the different methods. these methods vary or can be grouped based on type of execution im doing. so I am going to inherit the super class processing attributes but define all the different methods that needs to be processed.
I have function pointer mismatch error. could anyone suggest a solution for this issue

```
template <class T_ENUM> 
class Injection
{
public:
   Injection();
   ~Injection();
   virtual void    addAllCalls( void );
   bool            addCall( T_ENUM );

protected:
   void*           data;        // drive of device under test 
   struct call_info {
      T_ENUM  call_ref;
      string      time_stamp;
   };

   // class specific function pointer defenition
   // call_status_s is defined struct
   typedef void (Injection::*funcType)(call_status_s*);

   // map contains all calls initialized and ready to be processed
   std::map<T_ENUM, funcType>         func_call_map;

   // here i process the function pointer based on the T_ENUM
   bool   processCall ( T_ENUM );
   virtual void    initCallMap( void ); 
   // initialise the functions taken from child class and store here
};

class Type_Injection : public Injection<enum_defined_for_Type> {
public:
   void    addAllCalls( void );

private:
   void    initCallMap ( void );
    // would initialise func_call_map with the functions pointer of TypeFunction1

   // this is the function im going to save as pointers in the list defined in super class
   void TypeFunction1  ( call_status_s* );
};
```

compile error:

```
 error: cannot convert ‘void (Type_Injection::*)(call_status_s*)’ to
 ‘void (Injection<enum_defined_for_Type>::*)(call_status_s*)’ in
 assignment
```

Again sorry could not add the complete code.

Comment: Just to clarify, a "pointer-to-member-function" is not actually a function pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't typesafe, because you have a (hidden) covariant parameter.

The actual function `Type_Injection::TypeFunction1` requires a `this` argument of type `Type_Injection`.  But the call site is only providing an `Injection<enum_defined_for_type>` and not every instance of the latter actually is one of the former.

It may be that the actual parameter always is of the more derived type, in which case you can use a cast to override the compiler type checking.  But I would just use `std::function<void (call_status_s*)>` instead, and use `std::bind` when adding the callbacks to the map to specify the target object (assuming that the target object is always the class instance holding the map, and does not vary at call time).

```
typedef std::function<void (call_status_s*)> funcType;

// map contains all calls initialized and ready to be processed
std::map<T_ENUM, funcType>         func_call_map;

void Type_Injection::initCallMap ( void ) override
{
   using std::placeholders::_1;
   func_call_map[T_ENUM_FUNCTION1] = std::bind(&Type_Injection::TypeFunction1, this, _1);
}
```

In your particular case, another option is just to make your `processCall` function that takes in the `T_ENUM` selector `virtual`  (shouldn't it also accept the `call_status_s*` function argument to pass to the function being called?).  In the derived class, you can use a `switch` statement to map `T_ENUM` values to functions in the derived class.  This is very efficient, perfectly typesafe, and can delegate to the base class when the value doesn't match/isn't known, to allow different behaviors to be implemented in different levels of the class hierarchy.  Unlike a map this only allows lookup, so if iteration is a requirement the map of `std::function` would be a better option.

Another option is the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern", which allows the derived class to inform the base class of the real type of the object, so that the map can contain `void (DerivedType::*)(call_status_s*)` function pointers.  But this removes the ability to have behaviors provided at multiple levels of the call tree.

Comment: i tried to abstract the they way calls are made and child class to just handle setting up functions. but yes i could have used a switch case, i have 100-150 functions under some 200 features and was looking for a easy way to make code readable.
could you provide an example for using function and bind ?

Comment: @bicepjai: Example added.

Comment: initCallMap() is virtual, so i will be implementing inside the derived class Type_Injection and not in the parent class Injection. i still get  compile error [link](http://pastebin.com/sTbgaEzR)

Comment: @bicepjai: According to the compile error, you tried putting that implementation in the base class.  I designed it to go inside the derived class, just as you say you require.

Comment: t_injection.h from the [link](http://pastebin.com/sTbgaEzR) is derived class and  my base class in is in injection.h where i have the virtual functions declared. i dont have the virtual function implementation in the base class.

Comment: also in the sample code `typedef std::function<void (call_status_s*)>;` should be `typedef std::function<void (call_status_s*)> functType;` ??

Comment: @bicepjai: Good catch on the `typedef`.  In your error, `In member function ‘void Injection<T_INJ_ENUM>::initCallMap() [with T_INJ_ENUM = call_reference_enum]’` ... that's talking about an implementation in the base class.  Can you reduce it to a minimal compilable example?  Is the definition inline (between the braces that define the class) or out-of-line (after them)?